# Kubernetes Statefulset - Services for replicas

Tags: kubernetes

I am testing stateful sets with replicas, is there a way to force a service on each replica? For example, if I refer to the following note:

https://itnext.io/introduction-to-stateful-services-kubernetes-6018fd99338d

It shows headless service is created on top of pods. I do not have a way to force the connection to the first pod or the pod-0 or the 2nd pod i.e. pod-1.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the pods directly, or you can create headless services as you write. This headless service is not created automatically, it is up to you to create it.

> you are responsible for creating the Headless Service responsible for the network identity of the pods.

From [StatefulSet - Stable Network Identity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id)

Also see [StatefulSet Basics - Headless Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) on how to create headless services, by setting `clusterIP: "None"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do understand I can use podname-[0-N-1] identity for direct connection. Actually, in my case, I need to connect directly to each pod from outside using public IP.